# Profile performance for a given command

Tags: help, performance

Say I create a quick keyboard macro, but find that executing it in quick succession is extremely slow. How can I determine in what functions or packages this command is spending most of its time? Maybe some convenient help binding like `C-h %` which will then display the performance details for the next command executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs includes a CPU profiler for this purpose.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> [`(elisp)Profiling`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html) <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Should this binding run `info` from `info.el`?

Comment: Yes, that will display the node in question from the elisp manual.